# groovy code "(wangwang as Man).shout(10)" throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: groovy

I am new to groovy. I just wrote below code

```
public interface Man{
    public void say();
    public int shout(int x);
}

def wangwang = {
    println("wangwang!");
    println(it)
}

//(wangwang as Man).say()

(wangwang as Man).shout(10)
```

I run it in groovyConsole. and here's the output

```
wangwang!
10
Exception thrown

java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy18.shout(Unknown Source)
    at Man$shout.call(Unknown Source)
    at ConsoleScript10.run(ConsoleScript10:13)
```

It has prints out "10", so why does it throw an exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting scenario, indeed! I'd say that's because Groovy tries to cast the `null` value returned by `println` into `int` as defined by the interface. If you change return type of the method `shout` to void the problem goes away.

The problem goes away if you approach it from the other side - if you make the closure to return a value e.g.

```
def wangwang = {
   println("wangwang!");
   println(it)
   it
}
```

Or maybe if you try running the code below it may make the matter clearer

```
(println (10)).class
```